# AWS Credentials folder location

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to install the Amazon Web Services Python SDK. I cannot find the ~/.aws/credentials folder on my machine though.

This is the page I am using for reference: https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/

It says the location on Windows should be like: C:\Users\USER_NAME.aws\credentials

I've done pip installs for boto, boto3, and awscli. Is there something else I need to install to get a credentials folder?

Comment: You should create it yourself

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/) you posted...

> Create your credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials (C:\Users\USER_NAME.aws\credentials for Windows users) and save the following lines after replacing the underlined values with your own.

With the contents

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

There's nothing you need to install, just create the file, and put that in. (obviously swapping out `YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID` for your actual access key, and `YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` for your actual secret key ;) )

Comment: Is the file I create a python file or a text file?

Comment: @WilliamRoss it doesn't have an extension, it is just a text file called 'credentials'

Comment: On Windows / Apache, file should be placed on the root level in the same drive with your `httpd.exe`. For example my apache was installed on `E:\Server\Apache\ ` and when I put `E:\.aws\credentials` it worked. I found that by using ProcMon.exe from SystemInternals.